# Android: How to return back to previous activity when video is stopped playing?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

[image: video]

I'm playing video from raw folder. Generally once its completed it remains in same activity. how to return back to previous activity automatically without pressing back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) to Listen when Video Playing in finished in Activity 2 and start Previous activity on `onCompletion` as :

```
 videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
             //start Previous Activity here

            Current_Activity.this.finish();
        }
    }); // video finish listener
```

Comment: @Learner678 : i have answered this question first but you have accept other answer any problem with my answer?thanks

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a `VideoView` to play the video in your 2nd activity? If so, you can use the `OnCompletion` event to call `finish()` on the activity, which will return you to the 1st activity.

Something like this should work:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
        Log.i("VideoView", "onCompletion()");
        finish();
    }
});
```

Just be sure to replace `R.id.videoView` with the actual id in your layout file.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

After playing a video `onCompletion()` method is invoked, in that just call `finish()` method in it.